# Should I Hold references to fragments within my activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, reference, android-activity

My app has one `MainActivity` with three tabs (`A`, `B`, `C`).

Tab `A` shows `FragmentA1`. When I click a list entry in this fragment then `FragmentA2` is shown (still in tab `A`). The same applies to the other tabs, some hierarchies go even deeper (`FragmentC4`).

All the switching and replacing of all the fragments is handled in `MainActivity` by Listeners. (Edit: I don't define my fragment in XML layouts but in the code only).

My Question is:

**Should I hold references to all fragments in `MainActivity` or should I create them new everytime I need them?**

What are the (dis)advantages? Can I reuse fragments by using Alternative 1, instead of recreating them everytime?

Alternative 1:

```
class MainActivity

  private Fragment fgmtA1;
  private Fragment fgmtA2;
  private Fragment fgmtA3;
  ...
  public onClickItemInA1(int itemId) {
    fgmtA2 = new FragmentA2();
    // put args
    // replace
  }

...
}
```

Alternative 2:

```
class MainActivity
...
  public onClickItemInA1(int itemId) {
    FragmentA2 fgmtA2 = new FragmentA2();
    // put args
    // replace
  }  
...
}
```

Alternative 3:

Maybe the best solution is a completely different approach?

Comment: So you don't use the FragmentManager and methods like findFragmentById()?

Comment: No I don't at the moment. Should I use that? How? Maybe I should also mention that I don't definde my Fragments in XML but in the code only.

Comment: Store a reference or like @EdwardvanRaak mentioned, utilize Android's `FragmentManager` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)

Comment: Can I modify the content of a fragment when reusing ist? So can I do `Fragment fgmtA2 = ...findFragmentByTag(...); fgmtA2.putArgs(changedUrl);`?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I hold references to all fragments in MainActivity or should I
>   create them new everytime I need them?

It depends...
The only two reasons which i can think of are performance and keeping the state of a Fragment.

If you always create a new Fragment the GC will have a lot to do, which could cause some performance issues if you use a lot of bitmaps or huge data. You can reuse a Fragment by holding a reference to it in the Activity or getting the Fragment by tag or id using the methods [FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findfragmentbytag) or [FragmentManager.findFragmentById(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findfragmentbyid). With them you can reuse already created Fragments, which should be done by default.

Furthermore if your Fragments hold some data, you will lose them or you cache it somewhere else to reacreate it if the Fragment is destroyed. While reusing a Fragment you can use onSavedInstanceState() to reacreate your state.

Hence, yes you should reuse a Fragment because it could cause system performance or headaches using anti-patterns to save some data.

Comment: Thank your for your tips! At the moment I use Alternative 2 because I just thought the "opposite" way: If I'm holding references to all my fragments they never get GCed so all the large data the fragments hold is never GCed...

Comment: The GC will collect the Fragments if the Activity will be destroyed. But managing huge data of a Fragment is a question for itself.

Comment: I know I'm responding to Steve Bennett after 8 years, however, if your fragment has a "huge amount of data" that needs to be managed for it, you're probably misusing fragments.